# A better way of writing this code? Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, pagination, each

Ive got an array, which I do a few things to but right now im trying to divide it between 'pages' (more like slides really).

I loop through it using the `.each()` method, calling this lengthy bit of code to place the info on the right page (just 5 items per page, for now atleast).

Is there a way of simplifying this code?

Ideally so it can go on infinitely:

```
if (index > 0 && index <= 5) {
    var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-1');
} else if (index > 5 && index <= 10) {
    var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-2');
} else if (index > 10 && index <= 15) {
    var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-3');
} else if (index > 15 && index <= 20) {
    var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-4');
} else if (index > 20 && index <= 25) {
    var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-5');
} else if (index > 25 && index <= 30) {
    var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-6');
} else if (index > 30 && index <= 35) {
    var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-7');
} else if (index > 35 && index <= 40) {
    var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-8');
} else if (index > 45 && index <= 50) {
    var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-9');
}
```

Comment: Isn't there an error on the last line ? Shouldn't it be 40-45 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example :

```
var page = $('#librarian-page-gallery-' + Math.ceil(index/5));
```

Explanation :

```
   index/5 builds a float number :
         1 -> 0.2
         4 -> 0.8
         5 -> 1
         6 -> 1.2

   and Math.ceil returns the nearest greater or equal integer :
         0.2 -> 1
         0.8 -> 1
         1   -> 1
         1.2 -> 2
```

Comment: awesome, could someone explain what this line actually does though (how it works?). works perfectly though thanks

Comment: @rpsep2 I added a detailed explanation